# How To Deploy an Update to Python Flask Application with Gunicorn and Nginx on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, nginx, flask, gunicorn

**Python Flask / Gunicorn / Nginx newbie here.**

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) describing how to serve Flask Applications with Gunicorn and Nginx on Ubuntu 18.04.

Everything works and is up and running, no problem. However, my challenge is now that I would like to deploy an updated `myproject.py` file containing new code edits to the server. My question is do I simply just need to copy-paste the updated `myproject.py` file into the `myproject` folder such that it overwrites the old `myproject.py` file, and then the server will pick up these changes automatically? Or is there any specific commands I need to run for the changes to take effect or anything else I need to modify? What is the process for adding updated code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to restart the gunicorn service that you created in `/etc/systemd/system/myproject.service`

```
sudo systemctl restart myproject
```

Comment: I'm assuming that's it?

Comment: yes. you just need to restart gunicorn. no need to restart nginx.

Answer (score 0):

And you can use these:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
```